# three-dimensional arrays in c++ with openCV

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, multidimensional-array

I am trying to do three-dimensional arrays but my arrays is so big  like [92][112][200] .
Do I have alternative way to do 3D array to keep my value ? Or i don't know if i am doing something wrong. When I changed the size of dimension [50][50][50] i don't have any error like this.

my array

> Size s=imageX.size();
>
> int h = s.height;
>
> int w = s.width;
>
> double ThreeD[w][h][feature]

and my second question is : when i write the w or h to my array dimention ı have **error: Expression must have a constant value** can't i write the size of dimensions like this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with opencv.

Comment: How about a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors of vectors?

Comment: As for the errors, the message should be pretty self-explanatory. You can't use non-constant expressions as dimensions of arrays, as C++ doesn't (yet) have [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Comment: You need to use `new` to do dynamic allocation.

Comment: I have an image and  thought maybe there is solution with openCV Maybe I am new in c++ and openCV @Samuel

Comment: you can allocate a 1D matrix with size `w*h*feature` and access an element `[x,y,z]` with formula: `array[z*w*h + y*w + x]`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot (should not) declare an array like 3D with non-constant size. This array is allocated on the heap. Instead, you should allocate it using `operator new`.
Alternatively, you can create a 3D matrix in OpenCV using the number of channels as the 3rd dimension. But keep in mind in the number of dimensions is limited in cv::Mat (CV_MAX_CN =512 if I remember well). Here is how to do it (create a matrix of type float filled with zeros):

```
cv::Mat m = cv::Mat::zeros(imageX.size(), CV_32FC(feature));
```

Comment: If the matrix type needs to be double, that should `CV_64FC(feature)`. Also 512 is correct, but it should be CV_CN_MAX instead of CV_MAX_CN. I have coded 3D matrices this way and in my opinion it is much more convenient than trying to use a multidimensional Mat, as in berak's answer.

Answer (score 3):

#### [edit]: this answer is only here for completeness. please use @remi 's solution instead.

well you *can* use multidimensional Mat's in opencv:

```
int dims[3] = {92,112,200};
Mat m(3,dims,CV_32F);
cerr << m.size[0] << endl; 
// note, you have to use the size *member*, not the function now,
// also, rows and cols will be invalid(-1)
```

but really, make your life easy ,a and use a `vector<Mat>`:

```
vector<Mat> md(92,Mat(112,200,CV_32F));
```